# the sklearn.impute Iterativeimputer python

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

numeric_data = data.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64'])

imputer = IterativeImputer()
imputed_data = imputer.fit_transform(numeric_data)


imputed_data_df = pd.DataFrame(imputed_data, columns=numeric_data.columns)
```

---

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (22100, 38), indices imply (22100, 41)

the input dataframe is 41 columns ,however, the out put is 38 columns how could I solve this problem

Comment: Can you print the len(numeric_data) and the imputed_data.shape ?